# How do isAlive doesn't work in this example

Tags: c#, multithreading

i call one Thread

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

Thread R = new Thread(() => ramon(candle2h_close, "Buy", false));
```

i need to know if the process is alive or dead msa when i call isAlive da error

```cs
if (R.isAlive())
```

> 1>C:\Users\lucks\Desktop\Bot - Program.cs(307,23,307,30): error CS1061: 'Thread' does not contain a definition for 'isAlive' and no accessible extension method 'isAlive' accepting a first argument of type 'Thread' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I installed  nuget package System.Threading.Thread
but nothing worked

how do I check if this process is alive or dead?

Comment: sorted out  if (R.IsAlive)

Comment: Could you put proper language tag used?  I cannot figure out what programming language this is.

Answer (score -1):

Try with Debug,just mark the code line with the red dot and pres debug insetead of play